# Display the Total Balance

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

How to display the sum of Balances in the "Manage Gift Card Accounts" in magento admin control panel.   Customers => Gift Card Accounts

I want to display the sum of balances as Total at the bottom of the table.

Comment: Would that be the sum of Balances for the displayed list, or all the gift cards in the system?

Comment: Its the sum of balances for the displayed list

Comment: you can easily do that in the template, by just incrementing a running total value, every time that a row gets added. Adding it to the Model object might be more challenging.

Comment: Where should I locate the template file for the Gift Card Accounts, I am a beginner to magento

Comment: There is no special template for this page because it is ordinary magento backend grid.

Comment: Will you please make clear how to do this exactly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this file:
app/code/core/Enterprise/GiftCardAccount/Block/Adminhtml/Giftcardaccount/Grid.php

and

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/enterprise/giftcardaccount/sales/order/totals/giftcardaccount.phtml

This will give you some ideas.

I think it might need heavy surgery, to add a separate row down the bottom.

You might be better off doing a report.